# How to boot into Pavilion G series' BIOS

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, hp-pavilion

I have a brand new HP Pavillion G series laptop, which is running Windows 7. I need to boot into the BIOS, to change the boot order, so I can boot the laptop with a recently installed Norton Ghost recovery CD.

I've tried pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>F1</kbd>, but the boot continues into Windows.

Comment: Make sure you did not hibernate Windows on last use. Esc should work, and it's either F10 or F12 from memory that loads the one time boot menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All HP Notebooks with a UEFI bios

F10  Bios Setup

Esc  Display Startup Menu, shows you all the available F key options on your particular model.

F1  System Information

F2  System Diagnostics

F7 HP SpareKey  (select models)

F9  Boot Device Options

F11 HP System Recovery

F12  Network Boot  (Business Models)

After you enter the bios, F9 will load bios defaults

[More detailed Information here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01442956#N51)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to:

1. Let the Windows load.
2. Shut down the Windows (don't restart).
3. Turn on the laptop, wait for "Press ESC" for Startup Menu
4. It loads different startup menu that provides options like:

   F10 to enter BIOS
   F9 for boot options etc.

Answer (score 1):

Many incorrect answers here. Hold the Esc button down when you power the machine up, and wait for the menu to allow you into the BIOS, UEFI settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the login screen click the power icon with your mouse to bring up the 3 choices hover over restart, now hold shift, control, alt and use your last finger to press the left mouse button selecting restart. Hold the 3buttons still for about 5 seconds then let go....it will pull up the hidden menu options that allow you to do different things including factory reset but there's an option to change uefi startup option in bios...easiest and more options in this hidden menu...saved my Ardmore than once. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Press " Esc " , It will show the menu  and  Press F 10 to select the boot menu

or

Press SHIFT + CTRL + ALT and click " RESTART " , It will show the menu, there you can select the Boot options